# Solr: How to sort alpha-numeric field and range queries

Tags: string, sorting, solr

I have a simple data field with values Like A1, A2,...,A10,..R100 and so forth. I want to be able to sort them from A1 to Z100. Important is that A10 should appear before A2.

Also how can I then perform a Range query Like B5-D13?

Answer (score 0):

From your description a normal `StrField` should be enough. The sort order is the standard sort order for strings, and you can perform range queries on the fields as well.

Sorting is applied to the field by adding `&sort=field asc`, while the range query can be made by adding it to the query string (depending on the active parser) or applying a filter query: `&fq=field:[B5 TO D13]`.

This requires the field to be indexed.